# How to make a custom builder in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, ant

I want to copy my files from my source code directory to my local WAMP http directory for testing and I want to do it for each individual file when it is changed in Eclipse (css, php, etc).

I think the way to do this in Eclipse is to use a 'customer builder'. I've set one up that runs a batch file which (for now) just dumps out the argument passed in (${build_files:c}), which should be the list of files that have been changed. Instead, I'm getting the top level project path.

How do I get '${build_files:c}' to work (output a list of changed files) and what's the easiest way to achieve the copying (I assume ANT)?

Comment: Using apache vhosts to point your local server to your working directory would probably be easier than copying everything across.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that would be easier.